# Close popup window from a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, popup

I am working on an app that uses fragments, i am able to implement pop-ups from fragment but unable to implement dismiss functionality(getting run time exception) following is my code. can any one please help me identify what am i doing wrong here.

Code:

```
    {public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle        savedInstanceState) {

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    View fragView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newrun, container, false);

     entcal_button = (Button)fragView.findViewById(R.id.entercal_button);
     clear_button = (Button)fragView.findViewById(R.id.resetcal_button);
     cal_text=(EditText)fragView.findViewById(R.id.cal_amount);
     setuprunbuttonmethod();
     entcal_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {

            final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate(R.layout.workoutmode_popup,null, false),650,650, true);
            pw.showAtLocation(getView().findViewById(R.id.entercal_button),Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
            Button dismiss_button=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
            dismiss_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    pw.dismiss();
                }
            });
            }
        });}`
```

Comment: please add the error log, that would make it easier to find out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem lies in this line

```
Button dismiss_button=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
```

You are trying to find view in Button layout as `v` for this line is button (`entcal_button`).
Change `v` to layout that contains `dismiss_button` and you should be fine.

I would recommend to always use meaningful variable and method names as it helps to quickly find bugs. Good read about names - [Clean Code](http://www.itiseezee.com/?p=83).

Comment: Yes..mistake was exactly with the view, i created a new view for popup window and passed that view which had dismiss_button.Thanks a lot for the clean Code read,helped me quite a bit.